# Select data from one table where a field is greater than that of another field in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I want to be able to select data from TableA where Field1 is greater than Field2 in TableB.

In my head i image it to be something like this

```
    Select TableA.*
    from TableA
    Join TableB 
    On TableA.PK = TableB.FK

    WHERE TableA.Field1 > TableB.Field2
```

I am using SQL server 2005 and the TableA.Field1 and tableB.Field2 look like:

```
2004102881010 - data type - Vrachar
```

My PK and FK look like:

```
0908232      - data type - nvarchar
```

The probelm is when this query is ran ALL the data is displaying and not just the rows where Field1 is greater.

Cheers:)

Comment: So why doesn't that work? What error are you encountering?

Comment: Is the query you've shown us not working?

Comment: No its not working, it returning all the data, not just the rows that Field1 is greater.

Comment: Provide some sample data then for the PK, FK Field1 and Field2 fields.  Otherwise, look at your data types between field1 and field2, are they compatible? Are you getting an implicit conversion to varchar from int making things sort **funny**

Comment: updated. Let me know if you require more, cheers

Comment: More data if you would. SELECT PK, Field1 FROM TableA A WHERE A.PK = '0908232' and SELECT FK, Field2 FROM TableB WHERE B.FK = '0908232' might be useful to at least see what exists in both tables for a particular key.

Comment: are Field1 and Field2 dates in varchar format? or just numbers? when you say 'greater', you mean by quantity, yes? or by later date vs earlier date?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working correctly for this demo code. Perhaps I'm not understanding the problem or data.

```
;
with TABLEA (PK, Field1) AS
(

    -- Sample row that is filtered out
    SELECT CAST('0908232' AS nvarchar(10)), CAST('2004102881010' AS varchar(50))
    -- This is bigger than what's in B
    UNION ALL SELECT CAST('0908232' AS nvarchar(10)), CAST('2005102881010' AS varchar(50))
)
, TABLEB(FK, Field2) AS
(
    -- This matches row 1 above and will be excluded
    SELECT CAST('0908232' AS nvarchar(10)), CAST('2004102881010' AS varchar(50))
)
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableA.PK = TableB.FK
WHERE TableA.Field1 > TableB.Field2
```

Results

```
PK        Field1
0908232   2005102881010
```

Comment: Run your test again comparring CAST('2004102881010' as varchar(50)) with CAST('9' as varchar(50))

Comment: Why would I make that comparison? OP didn't provide data to indicate short values for Field1/Field2 was an issue. But I do agree that the string comparison is most likely the issue as noted in my above comment about things sorting funny

Comment: Re: Why would I make that comparison...because the demo code you wrote would sort a '9' *after* '2004102881010' (because it's doing a string comparison, not a number comparison).  I think that OP is looking for a number comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with missing zeroes:
20041028**0**81010

There is nothing wrong with your query, but your data.
Consider 2001-01-01 01:01:01, this would be seen as: 200111111
It should be seen as: 20010101010101

Answer (score 0):

Comparrison operators (>, <) used on strings (varchars, nvarchars, etc.) work alphabetically.  For example, '9' > '11' is true.  You might try doing a data type conversion...

```
WHERE cast(A.field1 as int) > cast(B.field2 as int)
```

Comment: @PDB -- Please provide a sample data set (specifically, data getting returned that *shouldn't* be getting returned.